# how to merge all field in single array in php for web service

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, web

```
{   
 "active_date":[
        "2016-12-24",
        "2017-01-03",
        "2016-12-24",
        "2016-12-24"
    ],
    "product_name":[
        "Spaces",
        "Samsung Galaxy J7 (2016)",
        "Nike Air",
        "HP Laptops"
    ],
    "product_category":[
        "Other",
        "Electrical & Electronics",
        "Men",
        "Electrical & Electronics"
    ],
    "old_price":[
        "1295",
        "14000",
        "2200",
        "35000"
    ],
    "nprice":[
        "799.00",
        "12500.00",
        "1800.00",
        "33000.00"
    ],
    "t_sale":[
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "t_return":[
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "availablity":[
        "10",
        "47",
        "9",
        "8"
    ]

}
```

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: what are you expected??

Comment: I want in this format......{  demo { action_date=''" ,product_name="",cat=""} }

Comment: Question is completely unclear. please put your input+your code effort+what is desired output+where you got problem and what?

Comment: [Duplicate] See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418279/how-to-reorder-a-multidimensional-array#41418329

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reorder a multidimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418279/how-to-reorder-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array decomposition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473313/php-multidimensional-array-decomposition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sample code:

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  foreach ($value as $index => $item)
  {
    $result[$index][$key] = $item;
  }

}
```

Comment: thank for your corporation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like,

```
$obj;// let it is your main object having all details
$newArr=array();
foreach($obj['active_date'] as $key=>$acd){
    $arr = array('active_date'=>$acd,
              'product_name'=> $obj['product_name'][$key],
              'product_category'=> $obj['product_category'][$key],
              'old_price'=> $obj['old_price'][$key],
              'nprice'=> $obj['nprice'][$key],
              't_sale'=> $obj['t_sale'][$key],
              't_return'=> $obj['t_return'][$key],
              'availablity'=> $obj['availablity'][$key]);
    $newArr[]=$arr;
}
```

**[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e627949693aadcd4e46281a686c6911c3d51e94)**

Alternatively you can use the simple one,

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($obj as $key => $items){
  foreach ($items as $index => $item){
     $newArr[$index][$key] = $item;
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4407bf2d73519bef5965c2b2a84be357e862892c)